# Capitalize the first letter in acronym list

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

When using the `acronym` package I would like to capitalize the first letter in the acronym description (e.g., Direct current). But when used in text I would like to have the word in lower letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{DC}{direct current}
\end{acronym}

Batteries run on \ac{DC}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

> DC direct current
>
> Batteries run on direct current (DC).

Comment: Welcome! Is the package `glossaries` an option for you?

Comment: Hmm, I like `\ac{DC}` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can patch the `\AC@@acro` macro that's responsible for printing the list of acronyms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother

%%% Alternative way (commented out because you may not have the package)
% \usepackage{regexpatch}
% \makeatletter
% \xpatchcmd*{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{DC}{direct current}
\end{acronym}

Batteries run on \ac{DC}.
\end{document}
```

### Update

With the most recent (2020) release of `acronym` things have changed (and may also change in the future). The right patch, current as of December 2020 is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname{{#3}}{{\MakeUppercase #3}}{}{}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname{{#3}}{{\MakeUppercase #3}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{DC}{direct current}
\end{acronym}

Batteries run on \ac{DC}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to capitalize the first letter of each word when printing the list of acronyms using `glossaries` package? But need to have lower case when used in text.

Comment: @Sndn That's a whole new question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481302/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-when-printing-list-of-acronyms

Comment: Note: As of TexLive 2020, this appears to no longer work. It seems that `\AC@@acro` is not patchable anymore? (`\ifpatchable*{\AC@@acro}{yes}{no}` prints "no" and I don't know enough to work around it).

Comment: @DisenchantedLurker Thanks for the call for action!

Comment: @egreg Wow, thank you, that was fast!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, that was really useful. As a side note, using `\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname{{#3}}{\capitalisewords{#3}}{}{}` with the `mfirstuc` package allows you to capitalise all the first letters of each word in the list of acronyms.

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion can be to define a new Command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*\FirstLetter[2]{#1}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{DC}{\protect\FirstLetter{D}{d}irect current}
\end{acronym}
\renewcommand*\FirstLetter[2]{#2}

Batteries run on \ac{DC}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
DC Direct current

Batteries run on direct current (DC).
```

---

Do work without `\protect` inside `\acronym` you can make the definition with `expl3`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \FirstLetter #1#2 { #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \FirstLetter #1#2 { #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```