# Using acronyms at start of sentence

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

I want it to capitalize the first letter of an expanded acronym used at the start of a sentence, like:

```
Application programming interfaces (APIs) are ...
```

I tried to define a new command \Acp for that purpose:

```
\usepackage[smaller,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\acro{API}{application programming interface}
\newcommand{\Acp}[1]{\MakeUppercase\expandafter\acp{#1}}
```

However when I use it, it doesn't work as desired:

```
\Acp{API} are ...
```

produces

```
application programming interfaces (APIs) are ...
```

Unfortunately I can not use the glossaries package which accomplishes exactly that due to interpackate-incompatibilities.

---

I had a similar desire in the list of acronyms where I also wanted to capitalize all first letters. There I redefined a different command as suggested in [Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list):

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother
```

That works.

Comment: What packages are you having a problem with in combination with ``glossaries``? (I think ``glossaries`` is probably the best solution to this problem, so I am hoping that one can identify and fix the incompatibilities.)

Comment: A duplicate to this question got more attention, and has an answer that might help, which I extended: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150798/28808

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind switching to a relatively new package you could use [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro). It naturally provides the command you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{relsize}

\acsetup{short-format=\textsmaller}

\DeclareAcronym{API}{
  short = API ,
  long  = application programming interface
}

\begin{document}

\Acp{API}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Since I did not want to change from acronym, for me the simple solution was as [mentioned in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244738/90539). Simply write the full acronym in your tet and then use the `\acused{API}` to mark it as used. See MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\title{Minimal Working Example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Some Section}
 Application programming interface \acused{API} (\ac{API}).

\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[MWE]
    \acro{API}{application programming interface}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works if you don't use `withpage`. Acronyms not spelled through `\ac` when first being used will have no page next to it in the acronym list.