# \Ac command not defined

Tags: acronyms

I use acronym package in my Latex file. Strangely, some of its commands, like `\Ac` are not defined when I compile my file. The `\ac` command works fine though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Physical Layer Security}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Ac{BER} is a metric. 

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{acronym}     
        \acro{BER}{bit-error rate}
    \end{acronym}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And here is the error I see:

`! Undefined control sequence. \Ac`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Thank you for including a minimal working example and the text of your error message.  I'm sure it won't be long before someone can help you.

Comment: Actually, even sooner:  somebody's already answered this question.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80003/capitalising-the-first-letter-of-an-acronym/150798#150798

Comment: You are probably using an old version of the package `acronym`. Take a look into the log file. The version should be 1.42 or higher. This version is on CTAN since yesterday

Comment: I have the latest version of the acronym package with MikTeX updated this morning and the compilation is not finished.

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: @gernotsaysReinstateMonica Where can I put the log file?

Comment: See https://miktex.org/faq, section Troubleshooting, question "where does miktex put diagnostic messages

Comment: @gernotsaysReinstateMonica I know where to find the log, but I don't know how to communicate it to you. It is too big to fit in a commentary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100994/discussion-between-gernot-says-reinstate-monica-and-andrec).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use version 1.42 of package `acronym` or higher for `\Ac` to work.

To check, take a look into the log file. You should find a line there that reads

```
Package: acronym 2019/11/11 v1.42 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)
```

If you get the error `Undefined control sequence. \Ac`, it is likely that you will find

```
Package: acronym 2015/03/21 v1.41 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)
```

instead.

Comment: I have the latest version of the acronym package with MikTeX updated this morning and the compilation is not finished.