# Questions regarding conversion from acronym package to glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In my thesis I use the `acronym` package. I have only one problem with the package, which is the lack of capability to capitalize first letter, a functionality which I read is provided by `\makefirstuc` in `glossaries`.

I have reservations though since I have already written most of the Thesis and I am wondering if it is too much trouble converting it, or should I seek ways to go around the limitation while sticking to `acronym`.

My questions are:

1. I make my own custom table for acronyms, because I want to conserve my own table style rather than rely on built-in ones from `acronym` or `glossaries`. As such, I need to be able to access the page reference labels that gives the page number the acronym was fist used. With `acronym` it is simply `\pageref{acro:label}`. Is there an analogue with `glossaries`?
2. To be able to build a custom table of abbreviations, I used the starred commands from `acronym` package, which does not mark the acronyms in the table as "used". This is important because otherwise all page references for the first use will point to the table itself. Does this problem exist with `glossaries` and if so is it solvable?
3. What are the direct equivalent in `glossaries` for the `acronym` commands of:

   ```
   \acs  %short form
   \acl  %long form 
   \acf  %long form (short form)
   \acfi  %emphasized long form (short form)
   ```

and their starred versions if any?

Comment: The custom table can surely be achieved by defining a custom glossary style (section 16 of the user manual). Then you won't need to worry about pageref at all. This would solve questions 1 and 2. Question 3 should be answered by a look into the [user manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries-user.pdf)

Comment: This question, [Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list), might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands for retrieving short and long forms of glossary entries and acronyms are described in detail in the [user manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries-user.pdf) in section 13.

Instead of writing my own table, though, I would suggest using `glossaries`' feature of creating a custom style for the list.

The example below should demonstrate how to define a custom style. `glossaries` comes with lots of examples so it is easy to follow the macros needed for the definition. Section 16 of the user manual describes everything in detail.

This only scratches the surface of the `glossaries` package. [One can use it for completely different tasks, too.](http://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?rd2&topic=172037&start=0#p1268240) And just in case it doesn't suit you after all: Nicola Talbot recently [described how to write your own glossary/acronym package](http://www.latex-community.org/component/content/article/55-latex-general/456-glossary-without-makeindex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\newglossarystyle{custom}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {%
      \begin{longtable}{lll}
       \toprule
        Acronym & Abbreviation & Reference \\
       \midrule
      \endhead
       \bottomrule
      \endfoot
     }%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*\glossaryheader{}%
  \renewcommand*\glsgroupheading[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*\glsgroupskip{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & \capitalisewords{##3} & p.\,##5\\}%
}

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{idn}{idn}{identification number}
\makeglossaries

% only for this example (!):
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms,style=custom]

\verb=\gls= \gls{ny} \gls{idn} \\
\verb=\gls= \gls{ny} \gls{idn} \\
\verb=\acrshort= \acrshort{ny} \acrshort{idn} \\
\verb=\Acrshort= \Acrshort{ny} \Acrshort{idn} \\
\verb=\ACRshort= \ACRshort{ny} \ACRshort{idn} \\
\verb=\acrlong= \acrlong{ny} \acrlong{idn} \\
\verb=\Acrlong= \Acrlong{ny} \Acrlong{idn} \\
\verb=\ACRlong= \ACRlong{ny} \ACRlong{idn} \\
\verb=\acrfull= \acrfull{ny} \acrfull{idn} \\
\verb=\Acrfull= \Acrfull{ny} \Acrfull{idn} \\
\verb=\ACRfull= \ACRfull{ny} \ACRfull{idn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `glossaries` also has the `shortcuts` option which defines `acronym` like macros for the usage of acronyms, see table 13.1 on page 91 in the manual for details.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful comments. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I have two problem with the page number references.
a) The double dashes -- do not convert to endash
b) How do I write a macro to count the number of entries of the comma separated page number to pluralize p. to pp. if there are more than one page?

Comment: This is a bit unspecific. Regarding a: are you by any chance using XeLaTeX and `fontspec` and forgot to load the font with `Ligatures=TeX`? It would be best to ask a new question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), maybe also refering to this question.

Comment: oops didn't know that is important to set that option; on a MWE with fontspec and setmainfont endashes work without Ligatures=TeX, which baffles me. But thanks alot, would be stuck otherwise.

Comment: Since with XeLaTeX you can insert a real endash (–) directly `--` is not converted automatically (the same for `---`). In order to get that feature `fontspec` provides the mentioned option. Strange that your MWE works without...