# Capitalization of the first letter in acronym list

Tags: acronyms, capitalization

How do I modify the `\acro` command from the `acronym` package in order to capitalize the first letter in the acronym list but still keeping a lower case letter in the text.

The accepted solution in:
[Capitalize the first letter in acronym list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57975/capitalize-the-first-letter-in-acronym-list?rq=1)
from isn't working. The alternative solution also doesn't work.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother

%%% Alternative way (commented out because you may not have the package)
% \usepackage{regexpatch}
% \makeatletter
% \xpatchcmd*{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{T}{test}
\end{acronym}

This is a \ac{T}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Uhm, it works for me...

Comment: Ok I changed to TeXstudio and it works but it doensn't work on on overleaf. Do you have any idead why? I'm using PdfLaTex on both @campa

Comment: @Someone `Overleaf` is a cloud based `LaTeX` system, and they have separate support group...

Comment: Works fine for me on overleaf too.

Comment: I can confirm the issue. It appears to be a change in the most recent versions of the acronym package. My TeXLive 2019 installation still works fine, but the 2020 doesn't capitalize.

Comment: Update: egreg has updated [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57987/) with a new version that works for the current version of `acronym`.